# infinity in the extended reals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, arithmetic, infinity

I learned about the extended reals a month ago in my measure theory class, and while the syntax for handling $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ is well defined, the mathematical properties of $+\infty$ in the extended real numbers hasn't been distinguished from the $+\infty$ that is derived from the naturals and used for sequences among other things.

To make things precise I shall denote $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ to denote the infinity used for sequences and $\infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ for the infinity used in the extended reals.

Now, I shall state what is common to both of them:

1. They are both non-computable.
2. The notion of a definite length or magnitude can't be made precise for either of them.
3. We can define a syntax of arithmetical rules that's similar for both of them. Ex:

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}} +x = y+ \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}, \infty_{\mathbb{N}} +x = y+ \infty_{\mathbb{N}}$

However, $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ for sequences like $(x_n)_{n=1}^N$ where $x_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{-n}$ can be defined within the context of a while loop that never ends. This can be made clear by the following pseudo-code:

**while $N \in \mathbb{N}$:**

**$x_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{-n}$**

**$N:=N+1$**

This loop, which never terminates, is what computer scientists call an infinite loop. Now, what happens if $u_n = n \pi$ and $y_n = 2n$.

At every increment of the loop, $y_n$ is an integer whereas $u_n$ is irrational. Yet, an analyst would say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$. However, given that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ originates from the positive integers does $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ simply refer to the set of naturals whose magnitudes we haven't bother to make precise?

Likewise, an analyst would say that:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n+2}=1$

but it would be more precise to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n+2}=1 +\epsilon$ where $|\epsilon|$ is the smallest positive rational that's greater than zero. I think the same could be said about all other limits using $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$. The epsilon almost vanishes but it doesn't. Unless  $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ is a mathematical object that doesn't originate from the positive integers.

But if that's the case, why have mathematicians defined arithmetical operations for $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$?

Now, as I have tried to reflect on $\infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ it appears that there are problems with $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$. These problems aren't unrelated but in my opinion must be resolved first. In fact, I don't think they are separate questions.

But, if it's possible to resolve the questions I've asked, I think it's natural to ask a further question. How is $\infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ semantically different from $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$? By this, I mean, what are its precise mathematical properties that distinguish it from $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$?

Right now, if I go through the list of arithmetical operations that are defined for $\infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$, it appears that these aren't sufficient to show that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} \neq \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$.

**Note 1:** 5xum points out that my notion of a smallest positive rational that's greater than zero is clearer within the context of non-standard analysis, and not within standard analysis. As a result of this discussion I shall try to learn non-standard analysis.

**Note 2:** This is not clear in the two answers so far but Stefan Perko shows in the comments below that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} = \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ for the following reason:

Given that $\infty :=\infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ is the greatest element of $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$. Assume $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{\bar{R}}$ such that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} \geq n$ for all naturals $n$. Then $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} \geq x$ for all reals $x$ by the Archimedian property. So it must be the same as $\infty$ (if it was a real there would be a greater real).

Comment: "where $\left| \varepsilon \right|$ is the smallest positive rational that's greater than zero", such number does not exist. Consider $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: **If** the *limit* of $f(n)$ for $n \to \infty$ is $1$, it is $1$, period, and not $1$ plus something.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. But here are some remarks: a) $\infty$ *is* computable. It is even implemented in most programming languages b) the symbol $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ has nothing to do with $\infty$ (if that's what you think). Limits are written like this for  historical reasons. c) $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} = \infty_{\mathbb{R}}$ because top elements in a lattice are unique.

Comment: See [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) for details and arithmetical operations.

Comment: What you're calling $\infty_{\Bbb N}$ is just a figure of speech, it generally does *not* denote a mathematical object. Think of the contexts it occurs in as idioms — "the $\Bbb N$-indexed sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$" or statements about limits. It is possible to interpret these same idioms in a way that's literal, by appointing some object to play the role of $\infty_{\Bbb N}$ with the desired properties. In the extended reals, $\pm \infty_{\Bbb R}$ *do* denote actual mathematical objects. However, in some elementary calculus discussions, they too may be treated as mere figures of speech.

Comment: @StefanPerko Is there a short proof that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} = \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$?

Comment: @BrianO I didn't know about this convention until I asked this question. However, Stefan Perko also says that $\infty_{\mathbb{N}} = \infty_{\mathbb{\bar{R}}}$ because top elements in a lattice are unique. I suppose the perspectives are reconcilable?

Comment: By definition $\infty := \infty_{\bar{\mathbb R}}$ is the greatest element of $\bar{\mathbb R}$. Assume $\infty_{\mathbb N}\in \bar{\mathbb R}$ such that $\infty_{\mathbb N} \geq n$ for all naturals $n$. Then $\infty_{\mathbb N} \geq x$ for all reals $x$ by the Archimedian property. So it must be the same as $\infty$ (if it was a real there would be a greater real).

Comment: Warning: you say "The epsilon almost vanishes but it doesn't", and you speak about "the smallest positive rational". Both of these terms are not true in standard analysis. There is no such thing as "smallest positive rational" in the standard reals. Hyperreals, sure. But only touch those once you are well versed in standard analysis.

Comment: @5xum Point taken. Point taken. I'll add a note to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is that $\infty_{\mathbb N}$ isn't really an element of any set. When talking about $\infty$ in sequences, saying $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$$ simply means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ if $n>N$.

So there is no $\infty_{\mathbb N}$ to speak of at all. The $\infty$ there is simply a symbol that describes a behavior, while in the extended reals, $\infty$ is an actual element of the set.

Answer (score -1):

$\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\infty_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ are not different notions - they're both just symbols standing in for "bigger than anything". Either can be used as an element of a set (for example, in the extended reals) but neither can be treated as "really" a number. For example, in the extended reals, no one ever tries to define $\infty - 1$, or (even worse) $\infty - \infty$. So think of the extended reals as the reals together with a couple of random objects - say, a horseshoe and a chipmunk - and a list of rules for what to do if you run into one of them in your calculations.

Another thing: "Origin" isn't really a thing to most mathematicians. The fact that your $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ is derived from the naturals and $\infty_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ from the reals doesn't mean they're different. For example, $\pi$ can be derived from a circle or from the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4(-1)^i}{2i+1}$; that doesn't mean we have two different versions of $\pi$, just two different ways of talking about the same thing.

And finally: $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ isn't just a stand-in for a natural we haven't specified yet - it's a very precise notion. $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) = L$ means "as $n$ grows *without bound*, $f(n)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$". That "without bound" is $\infty_{\mathbb{N}}$ - it's not saying the magnitude we're interested in hasn't been specified, it's saying that there *is* no fixed magnitude.

Comment: Again: $\infty$ has nothing to do with limits. See also the answer by 5xum.

Comment: @Stefan Perko That's an interesting perspective on 5xum's answer, since the most prominent component of it *is* a limit. I also have to disagree strongly with your comment elsewhere that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ is written that way only for historical reasons; the notation is a clear and natural extension of $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)$. Given a suitable interpretation of what it means to be "close to" $\infty$, the definitions are identical.

Comment: I'm claiming this is for historical reasons because an actual sound notation is just $\lim f$ (you take limits of sequences, not expressions). - I think limits of sequences are bit more fundamental then limits of functions (the latter can even be defined by the former). Buuut... you are right; perhaps my viewpoint is a bit *limited*.